# Odoo Client Error: "Widget type 'html' is not implemented" after database transfer (Odoo 10.0-20170708)

Tags: database, odoo-10, database-restore

I transferred an Odoo 10.0 database from one LinxuMint 18.2 machine to another and now experience client errors:

**(1)  when clicking Administrator > Preferences:  "Error: Widget type 'html' is not implemented"**

Nothing happens afterwards, no Preferences dialog window comes up! This is critical since the function is broken and not usable anymore.

**(2)  when clicking any other link:  "TypeError: this.$buttons.off(...).destroy is not a function"**

This error is scary but seems not the disturb the normal operations. After closing away the error pop-up window all operations seem to work normal so far.

Both error messages are only shown one single time after user login and don't repeat (but the Preferences window never comes up).

IMPORTANT: There is another database running on the server for testing, which has never been transferred and when using this database, there are no client errors or any other strange behavior. That seems to suggest that the database got damaged during the transfer. The commands which I used to backup the databases are the following:

```
Backup:   pg_dump --format=c databasename | gzip > database.sql.gz
Restore:  gzip -cd database.sql.gz | pg_restore -d postgres -C
```

I always delete and create a new database before restore. Am I doing something wrong? There were no errors during backup or restore.

Any clues or recommendations what I could do? Is there a function to repair an Odoo database? Is that robust and recommended?

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Below are the detailed error outputs or the errors:

**Error: Widget type 'html' is not implemented**

```
http://localhost:8069/web/content/512-fd02aef/web.assets_backend.js:2189
Traceback:
render_to/<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/512-fd02aef/web.assets_backend.js:2189:104
_.forEach@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:12:558
render_to@http://localhost:8069/web/content/512-fd02aef/web.assets_backend.js:2188:1796
start@http://localhost:8069/web/content/512-fd02aef/web.assets_backend.js:2124:261
OdooClass.extend/</prototype[name]</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:3010:556
__widgetRenderAndInsert/<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:3113:958
then/</</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:547:678
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
add@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:542:467
then/</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:547:631
each@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:370:758
then/<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:547:553
Deferred@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:548:189
then@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:547:518
__widgetRenderAndInsert@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:3113:879
appendTo@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:3113:92
switch_mode/<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/512-fd02aef/web.assets_backend.js:1697:39
then/</</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:547:678
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
add@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:542:467
then/</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:547:631
each@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:370:758
then/<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:547:553
Deferred@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:548:189
then@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:547:518
switch_mode@http://localhost:8069/web/content/512-fd02aef/web.assets_backend.js:1695:8
start@http://localhost:8069/web/content/512-fd02aef/web.assets_backend.js:1692:145
OdooClass.extend/</prototype[name]</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:3010:556
__widgetRenderAndInsert/<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:3113:958
then/</</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:547:678
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:546:198
updateFunc/<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:549:482
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:546:198
then/</</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:547:849
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:546:198
then/</</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:547:849
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:546:198
Deferred/</deferred[tuple[0]]@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:548:31
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:546:198
then/</</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:547:849
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:546:198
then/</</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:547:849
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:546:198
done@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:937:86
callback@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:957:15
```

**TypeError: this.$buttons.off(...).destroy is not a function"**

```
http://localhost:8069/web/content/512-fd02aef/web.assets_backend.js:2900
Traceback:
destroy@http://localhost:8069/web/content/512-fd02aef/web.assets_backend.js:2900:850
OdooClass.extend/</prototype[name]</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:3010:556
destroy@http://localhost:8069/web/content/512-fd02aef/web.assets_backend.js:1625:320
clear_action_stack/<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/512-fd02aef/web.assets_backend.js:1639:212
_.collect@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:13:270
clear_action_stack@http://localhost:8069/web/content/512-fd02aef/web.assets_backend.js:1639:157
push_action/<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/512-fd02aef/web.assets_backend.js:1633:135
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:546:198
Deferred/</deferred[tuple[0]]@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:548:31
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:546:198
Deferred/</deferred[tuple[0]]@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:548:31
load/</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/512-fd02aef/web.assets_backend.js:3988:1014
then/</</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:547:678
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:546:198
updateFunc/<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:549:482
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:546:198
Deferred/</deferred[tuple[0]]@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:548:31
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
add@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:542:467
then/</</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:547:753
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:546:198
then/</</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:547:849
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:546:198
then/</</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:547:849
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:546:198
Deferred/</deferred[tuple[0]]@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:548:31
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:546:198
then/</</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:547:849
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:546:198
then/</</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:547:849
fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:541:281
fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:546:198
done@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:937:86
callback@http://localhost:8069/web/content/508-32fb078/web.assets_common.js:957:15
```

Comment: Small but hopefully useful addition: I just found that the errors do **not** show after activating **developer mode (with assets).** Also accessing the administrator preferences works in that case. Interesting to note that in developer mode _without_ assets the errors do appear as before.

Answer (score 3):

Run this on the affected DB:

`DELETE FROM ir_attachment WHERE datas_fname SIMILAR TO '%.(js|css)'`